Column spacing when using multicolumn
Trying to make a binder plate for a report but one person has an excessively long title which is throwing off the spacing of the bottom rows. Ideally the logos and adresses would be the same size for both.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[b]
\centering
\resizebox{.81\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|llcccl|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Submitted by:}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Mr. Nellie Bayer}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Normal Title}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Checked by:}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Odessa McClure}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Normal Title}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Approved by:}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Eladio Gislason}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Excessively Long Title}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{Issued for Company:}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Date}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{figures/Logo1.png}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Place Name} & \multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{figures/logo2.png}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Place Name} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{123 Apple ST} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{321 Orange Dr} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Springfield 12345} & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Springfield 12345} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE. Just to be sure I understand your formatting objective: Do you want the fourth column to have the same width as the first? Please advise.

Some observations: (1) \resizebox is almost never a good idea, as it ruins the consistency of your document. (2) Please complete your document with \documentclass, \begin/end{document} and the required packages to make it compile.

The width of c and l (and r) columns, including \multicolumn, is determined by their contents. If you want some columns to have equal widths, you should specify the width explicitely, with p{xxx} or similar, or use the tabularx package with the X specifier. The tabularray package has similar provisions.

Like this:

With use of the tblr od tabularray Package and X columns type the MWE is:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[b]
    \centering
\adjustboxset{height=15mm, 
              width=\linewidth, % dropout in real document
              valign = m,
              }
\begin{tblr}{width   = 0.8\textwidth,
             colsep  = 2pt,
             colspec = {*{6}{X[l,m]}},
             cell{1-3}{odd} = {c=2}{},
             cell{4}{1,4}  = {c=3}{c},
             cell{5}{2,5}  = {c=2}{c},
             row{1-4}= {font=\small\bfseries},
             hlines, vlines}

Submitted by:   &&  Mr. Nellie Bayer    &&  Normal Title            &   \\
Checked by:     &&  Odessa McClure      &&  Normal Title            &   \\
Approved by:    &&  Eladio Gislason     &&  Excessively Long Title  &   \\ 
Issued for Company:     &&&         Date    &                       &   \\
\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
                &   {Place Name\\
                    123 Apple ST\\
                    Springfield 12345} 
                        &&   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
                                &   {Place Name\\
                                     1 Orange Dr\\
                                     Springfield 12345}             &   \\
\end{tblr}%
    \end{table}
\end{document}

As You can see, for inserting images are used instruction defined in the adjustbox box. Size of images is set by \adjustboxset. You probably accommodate used settings to real images in table.
